# How can I get SNAT to work with ARP requests using iptables?

Tags: iptables, nat, arp

**Problem Statement** 
I have two nodes (N<sub>1</sub> and N<sub>2</sub>) on separate networks.  They both connect to separate interfaces on a common node (N<sub>c</sub>).  I need to ping from N<sub>1</sub> to N<sub>2</sub>.

*Reference*:
N<sub>1</sub>: IP Address 172.1.1.96/24 
N<sub>2</sub>: IP Address 10.1.1.33/24 
N<sub>c</sub>: lan1 10.1.1.1/24
      lan2 172.1.1.1/24

______________________________________________________________
|                                              /          N<sub>c</sub>         \                                                     |
| N<sub>1</sub> <------>| Switch<sub>1</sub> |<-------> | lan2  <--> lan1 | <-------> | Switch<sub>2</sub> | <-------> N<sub>2</sub> |
| _______________________\___________/__________________________ |

**Attempts**

I've added a routing rule to N<sub>1</sub> to send all 10.1.1.0/24 packets to 172.1.1.1 (N<sub>c</sub>), and the following iptables rule to N<sub>c</sub>:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.1.1.96 -o lan1 -j SNAT --to 10.1.1.79
```

I then send a ping to N<sub>2</sub> from N<sub>1</sub>. N<sub>2</sub> receives the ping and sends an ARP request.  This ARP is not answered by N<sub>c</sub> causing N<sub>2</sub> not to respond to the ping.

**Question**
How can I get N<sub>c</sub> to answer the arp request?

*Note*

I can not use masquerading. Once I figure this out, I will start adding more complex translation rules that I don't think are possible using masquerading.

Comment: A down vote without an explanation is completely unhelpful!  The only way I can improve the quality of my questions is when someone points out what is wrong with it.

Comment: The only reason I can think of is that this seems to be more related to networking, and doesn't have anything (directly) to do with programming. If that's the case, the post should be flagged to be moved to a more appropriate SE, rather than downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxy ARP is the solution.  By setting proxy_arp or proxy_arp_pvlan flag (see [serverfault post](https://serverfault.com/a/212139) for explanation for which to use), Linux will respond to ARP requests from N<sub>2</sub> in behalf of N<sub>1</sub>.